# If I do not specify [httpGet] or [httpPost] for the action method , what will be the rule for calling it

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, http

Previously as many articles mentioned that HttpGet is the default http method. For example if I have the following action method inside asp.net mvc web application, without any [httpGet] or [HttpPost]:-

```
Public ActionResult TestMethod(int I =0)
```

So I thought that this action method will be defined as Get action method, and will NOT be reachable if I send Posr request as follow `“POST http://severname/test/TestMethod?i=1”`.

But seems that my action method will be available for both Post & Get requests, when I do not specify any http method. So as I know that HttpGet is the default , but seems this is not the case? Or I am missing something about what does httpGet is the default mean?
Can anyone advice please?
Thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

What I understand, By default It accept both type of request whether it is GET or POST. but when a action method is decorated with either [httpGet] or [httpPost] attribute then the action method accepts only those request method which define by attribute.

Comment: so not specifying any thing will make the action method to be avilable for both GEt & POST ?

Comment: Exactly john, if you not define any attribute on the action method then it accepts both GET & POST

Comment: Assuming of course that you don't add one and not the other. For example, if you have the same action name, one with no attribute and the other with `[HttpPost]`, then the one without an attribute is implicitly GET only.

Comment: @ChrisPratt yes exactly this is another valid point, let say i define an action method without specifying if it is a Get or Post, then i define another action method with the same name and i define it as Post action method. then ley say i call the following "POST Http /actionmethodname/", then which one will be called ? and what governs this ? is this the Routing system responsibility ? thanks

Comment: @John For sure, the post action method will be called. And I think this is the responsibility of controller factory.

Comment: Is this the case for razor pages too? For example would OnTest be the same as OnGetTest & OnPostTest